# django import error: No module named comment?

Tags: python, django

I'm building a little django 'guestbook' app that make visitors to leave comments. But I keep getting 'django import error: No module named comment'. How should I solve it?
When I click submit button error traceback pops up, but strangely user input is saved fine in DB.

Traceback:

```
ImportError at /comment/1/like/
No module named 'comment'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://192.168.56.101:8000/comment/1/like/?csrfmiddlewaretoken=2fPYLRu9acVTcRDxfgXqwYEFMxNs2dbb&comment_id=1
Django Version: 1.7.6
Exception Type: ImportError
Exception Value:    
No module named 'comment'
Exception Location: /home/web/venv/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py in import_module, line 109
Python Executable:  /home/web/venv/bin/python
Python Version: 3.4.2
```

Views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from guestbook.models import Comment

def index(request):
    context = {
                "comments" : Comment.objects.all()
    }
    return render(request, "index.html", context)

def comment_submit(request):
    try:
        name = request.POST["name"]
        contents = request.POST["contents"]
    except (KeyError):
        return redirect('index')
    else: 
        comment = Comment(name = name, contents = contents)
        comment.save()
        return redirect('index')

def comment_like(request, comment_id):
    comment = get_object_or_404(Comment, id=comment_id)
    comment.like = comment.like + 1
    comment.save()
    return redirect('index')
```

Models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class Comment(models.Model):
    name     = models.CharField("User Name", max_length=100)
    contents = models.CharField("Contents", max_length=100)
    like     = models.IntegerField("Like", default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s: %s" % (self.name, self.contents)
```

URLS.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^$', 'guestbook.views.index', name="index"),
    url(r'^comment/submit/$', 'guestbook.views.comment_submit', name='comment_submit'),
    url(r'^comment/like/$', 'guestbook.views.comment_like', name='comment_like'),
    url(r'^comment/(?P<comment_id>\d+)/like/$', 'comment.views.comment_like'),
)
```

Template:

```
{% if error_message %}
<script>
alert('{{error_message}}')
</script>
{% endif %}
<br />

<div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>Welcome to Guestbook!</h1>
        <br />

        <form method="POST" action="/comment/submit/" class="form-horizontal">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="form-group ">
                <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">이름</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="name" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="이름">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group ">
                <label for="contents" class="col-sm-2 control-label">내용</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="contents" name="contents" placeholder="내용">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group ">
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="submit" class="register btn btn-default" id="register" value="등록">
                </div>
            </div>
        </form> 

        <div>
            <table class="list table">
                <!-- Get data from model, which is saved by using Admin -->
                {% for comment in comments %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{comment.name}}: {{comment.contents}} +{{comment.like}}</td>
                    <td>
                        <form method="GET" action="comment/{{comment.id}}/like/">
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            <input type="hidden" value="{{comment.id}}" name="comment_id">
                            <input type="submit" value="추천">
                        </form>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </table>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the last url conf should be guestbook.views

Comment: Thanks. I got it. @hsfzxjy